# Variable Scope outside foreach loop Perl

Tags: perl, for-loop, foreach, scope, nested

Here is the problem:
Generating 10 iterations of 50 iterations and accessing the 50 character string outside the inner foreach loop.

I have tried putting the 50x iteration inside a sub function and calling it, but that was unsuccessful.
Thus far, I only get a single character outside the foreach loop whether it's in a sub function or not. I'm fairly certain this is a scope issue that I'm failing to see.

So, code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dna = ('A','G','T','C');
my $i;
my $str;

for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
    #print $i . " ";

    foreach(1..50){
        my $nt = int(rand $#dna + 1);
        $str = $dna[$nt];
        #correct here all 50 nts
        print $str;
    }

#single nt here
#print $str;
print "\n";

}
```

Output: Corerct, but I need to access $str as is below but ***outside*** the foreach loop **and** within the first for loop.

TGATTAGCGTCCGCGCGTATTGTATTAAGCCACAGAATGTAATGCCAAGA
GCTATAGGAAGACGCCGATCCCTGGACCGGCACAGGCACGGTAACAGCAG
TTGTTGTAGGATCCCAGGGAGCGAAGCACGTGAACTGCGACTAATTTCAA
TAACCAGGCAACACTAAACAGCTCCCATGTGTAAGGACGTATAGGCAGTT
GTAATTGTAGATCACAAAATTTACACGGTATAGCATTAACTGGAACCTGC
AACAGTGCCGTTTATTAATCTCCTCTAGTGTAGGGACGAATCGACCACGG
CGTGAGCAAGCACAAATATCCTTTAGGGGTGTGCTTAAAACACCCAGTAG
GAGTTCATAGGCCAACAATATGGCAAAGCCTTGCCCCATCAAATTCGGCG
TTGCGTCTGCGAACACTGTTGGTGTGCCTTTAGTGCGGGTTACTCGAGAA
CGCGATCTCCGTTTATAACGCTAGCAAACTACTACGGACCGAGGCATCGC

I removed the extra space in the string. It was superfluous.

This was another attempt at getting to the variable to no avail:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str;
my @dna = ('A','G','T','C');

for (my $i=1; $i<11; $i++){
    fifty();
    print $str;
}

sub fifty {
    foreach (1 .. 50){
        my $nt = int(rand $#dna + 1);
        $str = $dna[$nt];
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Comment: "_new to Perl and tempted to write this in something else_" -- this has nothing to do with Perl (or else) ... you're clearly assigning a char (+space) to `$str` (`=`) in every iteration.  What do you expect -- to have all 50 after the loop?  Then you want to add, `.=`

Comment: With the edit now `$str` is only one character (no space anymore) so the output can't be what's shown. again, nothing to do with languages. But, how did my previous suggestion work, to have `$str .= $dna[$nt];`  (Instead of `=`) ? That way it builds `$str` to 50 characters.  (If that's what you want, the question isn't clear)

Comment: That is the regenerated output. 10 iterations of 50. Regardless of the language, I still think it's a scope problem that I can't figure out. So far, nothing too helpful but I'll try again after a night's sleep

Comment: Um, I am telling you (twice) what it is:  You _assign_ to `$str` every time, so it always has one character, and after the loop it's the last one that was assigned.  What you see is the accumulated print out.   Change `$str = $dna[$nt];` to `$str .= $dna[$nt];` and after the loop with 50 the `$str` will be 50 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to work perfectly: Turns out to be scope as far as I could tell and not sure why I was stuck. Regardless, moving on now.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dna = ('A','G','T','C');
my $i;
my $str;

for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
    my $filename = "seq_" . $i;
    open(my $OUT, '>', $filename) or die("Can't open $filename($!)");

    foreach(1..50){
        my $nt = int(rand $#dna + 1);
        $str = $dna[$nt];
        print $OUT $str;
    }

close $filename;

}
```

Comment: I know why youe were stuck: You do not yet understand programming. Sorry if that sounds harsh, but your issue is not related to variable scope.

Comment: @Skeeve I was wrong in assuming scope, but in fact it kinda was considering what I was trying to do. I figured it out myself anyways. You're comment is quite rude. I don't appreciate it. Your "sorry" means nothing.

Comment: The issue is: You got really helpful answers from zdim, but it seems you didn't understand. Your code clearly shows that you didn't even try to follow his advice. Instead of trying to understand the most basic priniciple you created your own workaround. If you're happy with that, be happy. Still it leaves the impression I've stated above.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
for (my $i=1; $i<11; $i++){
    fifty();
```

In`fifty`you return something but you discard ist, as you do no assignement like `$str= fifty();`

```perl
    print $str;
}
```

And here you print something that has no value yet as it seems - in fact you assign a value in `fifty`- but you shouldn't use global variables.

```perl
sub fifty {
    foreach (1 .. 50){
        my $nt = int(rand $#dna + 1);
        $str = $dna[$nt];
```

Here you discard whatever is in `$str` and assign one letter instead. Also you assign to a global variable - which you should avoid.

```perl
        return $str;
    }
}
```

And here you directly leave `fifty` and return just the one character - which you (see above) discard.